# Problemas al ejecutar EXECUTE IMMEDIATE en una función y/o procedimiento

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

estoy tratando de ejecutar un comando `EXCECUTE IMMEDIATE` en `ORACLE`en una función que se encuentra dentro de un `package`. He tratado de crear primero una tabla con los siguientes comandos:

```
package body any_package as 
function any_function (any_number number)return number
is any_number2 number;
begin
    execute immediate 'create table any_table (any_value number)';
    return 1;
end;
end any_package;
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

> ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL , commit or rollback inside a query
>   DML

Por otro lado, cuando creo la tabla he inserto datos en la nueva tabla con el siguiente comando:

```
package body any_package as 
function any_function (any_number number)return number
is any_number2 number;
begin


    execute immediate 'insert into any_table (any_value) values (7)';
    return 1;
end;
end any_package;
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query

creo que se debe a permiso, ya que no es mi motor de base de datos sino de la empresa en la cual laboro. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es el procedimiento en sí, ni tampoco es un problema de permisos. Mas bien, el problema es la *forma* cómo lo ejecutas.

Aunque no lo has mostrado (en el futuro, siempre deberías incluir un [script mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para este tipo de preguntas), es obvio por el error que estás ejecutando la función como parte de un query o select. Por ejemplo, algo como:

```
select any_package.any_function(1) from dual;
```

Lo que el error te está diciendo es que si llamas una función como parte de una consulta, no tienes derecho a modificar datos en esa función.  Y en efecto, no tiene sentido que el correr una consulta tenga por efecto de modificar datos.

Si necesitas modificar datos usando una función, debes ejecutarlo fuera de una query, tal vez usando un bloque PL/SQL, o llamándolo de otro procedimiento.

Ejemplo:

```
declare
  result number;
begin
  result := any_package.any_function(1);
end;
/
```

Adicionalmente, te menciono que el `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` solo es necesario para sentencias DDL, como `CREATE`, `ALTER`, etc. No necesitas SQL dinámico para sentencias DML como `INSERT`, etc.

Comment: te entiendo, lo que sucede que tengo que hacer todo ese `package`, ya que lo estoy llamando de un aplicación en `.net` el cual hace que la consulta sea demasiado lenta. Por ello, tengo que hacerlo todo dentro de un `package`. Las querys las tengo listas simplemente para ejecutarlas. Lo llamo a traves de `select any_package.any_function(1) from dual;` dentro del  `.net`  como lo mencionas. Lo que tú me aconsejas es llamarlo dentro de otra `function` dentro del mismo `package`?

Answer (score 1):

procede a colocar la sentencia `pragma autonomous_transaction;`antes de inciar el `begin` de la `function` de tu `package`. Si así fuese, ya no necesitarías la la sentencia `execute immediate`

```
package body any_package as 
function any_function (any_number number)return number
is 
pragma autonomous_transaction;-->Se coloca antes del begin de cualquier function
any_number2 number;
begin
    create table any_table (any_value number);
    return 1;
end;
end any_package;
```

De igual forma:

```
package body any_package as 
function any_function (any_number number)return number
is 
pragma autonomous_transaction;-->Se coloca antes del begin de cualquier function
any_number2 number;
begin
    insert into any_table (any_value) values (any_number);
    return 1;
end;
end any_package;
```

Comment: Cuidado, 1) esto no cambia el hecho que no puedes hacer un `create table` dentro del package como en tu primer ejemplo.  2) hay que entender que esto hace que el insert no participe en la transacción del que ejecuta el package. Eso rara vez es lo deseado.